# How to specialize a nested class for template template parameter of the enclose class

Tags: templates, nested, template-specialization, template-templates

Given:

```
template<typename T> 
struct Foo
{
    template<typename U>
    struct Bar {};

    /* many more members */
}
```

and

```
template<typename F> 
struct Zoo {};
```

I need that only Bar will be specialized for when enclose class Foo is of type of `Foo<Zoo<F>>` whatever F is.
I don't want to partial specialize Foo for `Zoo<F>` because I need then to declare all its members again.

I don't understand why the follow won't compile:

```
template<typename F>
template<typename U>
struct Foo<Zoo<F>>::Bar {}
```

because I would expect `Foo<Zoo<F>>` to be treated as the primary Foo template , where its template parameter is set to `Zoo<F>`, and only Bar should be specialized.

Answer (score 0):

A friend gave me the solution and I share.

According to the c++ standard :

> “Each class template partial specialization is a distinct template and definitions shell be provided for the members of a template partial specialization”

That's is the reason why the code won't compile. `Foo<Zoo<F>>` is a partial specialization of Foo and in this case, according to the C++ standard, the compiler doesn't use the primary template but expect for a distinct definition.

**Solution 1: Define partial specialization of enclosing class**

We must define first the specialization for  `Foo<Zoo<F>>` but if we already define it, then we actually can specialize Bar within this definition.

```
// partial specialization of Foo 
template<typename T> 
struct Foo<Zoo<T>>
{
    template<typename U>
    struct Bar { /* specialize declaration for Bar here */ };

    /* many more members - should be define here as in the primary template of Foo */
};
```

This will give the desired results, but the problem is that we have to define all Foo other members again in the specialization.

**Solution 2: Move declaration of nested class into a base class**

```
// base class contains only declaration of Bar
template<typename T> 
struct FooBase
{
    template<typename U>
    struct Bar {};
};

// Foo contains other members, but also derived from FooBase
template<typename T> 
struct Foo : public FooBase<T>
{
    /* many members */
};
```

In order to specialize Bar for when Foo is of type of `Foo<Zoo<T>>` , we define the partial specialization of FooBase.

```
// partial specialization of FooBase 
template<typename T> 
struct FooBase<Zoo<T>>
{
    template<typename U>
    struct Bar { /* specialize declaration for Bar here */ };
};
```